# Why does Jupiter return to cleaning toilets?

Tags: jupiter-ascending

In Jupiter Ascending, the main character starts out as a maid. Later, she

> Finds out she owns the earth

Shouldn't that change her socioeconomic status? Why does she keep scrubbing toilets?

Comment: I wondered the same thing! I've been meaning ask this, great question. :)

Comment: The answer to this question (and indeed ever other Jupiter Ascending question) is that the film is a badly written mess

Comment: @Richard Standard Richard meme alert!

Answer (score 13):

I thought it was obvious. Humility. She *never* wants to be like the others. They disgust her.

> **Balem Abrasax:** [scoffing] *No, my mother never cleaned a toilet in her life.*
>
> **Jupiter Jones**: *Maybe that was her problem*

Answer (score -3):

she is probably dealing with PTSD = post traumatic stress disorder and doing what she is familiar with to ground herself and get her mind in order before she does whatever is necessary to ensure the survival/ non harvesting of earth

They also assumed it would do well enough to warrant a sequel which would have shown her being a Commonwealth Universal Revolutionary/ Entitled trying not to live the decadent life of an entitled

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this supposed sequel?